# Drawbacks to alpine images in dockerhub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

Are there any drawbacks to using alpine docker images? Why even have other images when you have alpine?
I find myself mostly using alpine images since they are so fast to pull.

Comment: A simple reason would be some packages need packages only available in non-alpine distros. It may be possible to get a specific version of `gcc` using `apk` but much easier for new Docker users to use `apt` in Debian based distros to download dependencies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most Linux use libc for the C library, while Alpine uses musl.
You can sometimes encounter subtle bugs because of that.
Keep that in mind if something weird happens.

That being said, I mostly use Alpine for my containers

Comment: what kind of bugs exactly ? I am planning to run a Java application in alpine based container. Anything in specific that I should look for ?

Comment: exemple https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=187485